# Google sheets: get the price automatically according to the First In, First Out method

Tags: google-sheets

I have a detailed spreadsheet with a list of different products (about 1000 - the sheet 'Products' is a shorter example). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_OGWq1SLUcPOSmcXAfzn1ySW4kOtwn2sFroAtlLpKQ/edit?usp=sharing

On the sheet IN/OUT I enter the date, the number of units, the name of the product purchased or sold (Column E to select purchased or sold.).

In column N I enter manually the Price per unit purchased. So the same product can be purchased for different prices in different dates.

I would like to get the price in column O automatically when I enter the data about the sold product. But the first purchased must be sold first. There is more explanation in the example spreadsheet.

Is it possible to do this somehow? (picture edited)
[image]

Comment: How would the output look like? Will it be simply the `6.43` value? If that is the case, will this `=INDEX(FILTER(O3:O13;NOT(ISBLANK(O3:O13)));ROWS(FILTER(O3:O13;NOT(ISBLANK(O3:O13)))))` work for your situation? Or do you want to return something like `Product 1 - 6.43`, `Product 3 - 1`? If none of these, would you mind sharing the desired output as well?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bu it returns something different I suppose...

Comment: yes, indeed, the name of the product must be taken into account!

Comment: . I want to get 5 in O5 cell, because there are 10 units of this product in stock: 5 units purchased for 5$ and 5 units purchased for 7$. So, when I sell 3 units, these are units from the first purchase, so the sell price is 5$. Bu when I sell this product for the next time and sell 7 units, then the price would be 6,45$ for each f these 7 units, because 2 units of 7 had the purchase price of 5$ and the other 5 units of 7 had the new purchase price of 7$.

Comment: When I sell this product for the next time (not shown at the picture) there will be no price of 5$ any more, because all the first 5$ units were sold out.

Comment: I understand your goal! It's a bit complex, I'll keep working on it and try to find a solution. Usually in logistics people work instead of the average price for all the stock. Your idea is different and may be more complex to find a formula. I'm not sure to succeed, maybe in a few days!

Comment: Ok, thank you! I would greatly appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Natalie : Let me know if it is correct! I have performed some trials and it seems good!

Comment: I will also work on the average cost/price of the remaining stock... here is an interesting publication: https://opentextbc.ca/principlesofaccountingv1openstax/chapter/calculate-the-cost-of-goods-sold-and-ending-inventory-using-the-periodic-method/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom function

```
function sellPrice() {
  var begin = 3
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var currentRow = sh.getActiveRange().getRow()
  var data=sh.getRange(begin,1,currentRow-begin+1,18).getValues()
  if (data[currentRow-begin][4]!="Sold"){return}
  var product = data[currentRow-begin][10]
  var alreadySold = 0
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if (data[i][10] == product && data[i][4] == 'Sold' && i < (currentRow-begin)){
      alreadySold += data[i][2]
    }
  }
  var toBeSold = data[currentRow-begin][2]
  var price = 0
  data.forEach(function(row){
    if (row[10] == product && row[4] == 'Purchased'){
      var qty = Math.max(Math.min(row[2] - alreadySold,toBeSold),0)
      alreadySold -= row[2] - qty
      toBeSold -= qty
      price += qty * row[13]
    }
  })
  return (price/data[currentRow-begin][2])
}
```

to use it :

```
=sellPrice($O$1)
```

check / uncheck on O1 to re-calculate if necessary
[image]

I also made a comparison between FIFO and AVG with at the end the same situation. AVG offers less variations.

[image]

Comment: And it was a big challenge! so complex to develop that a simple formula was not enough. Maybe one of the tricks I'm proud of!

Comment: I can't see my previous comment, in which I thanked you a lot!! This function is fantastic! I thought that it was not possible to manage it. Now I'll apply it to my original spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw your comment which disappeared! weird!